# Do I really need to create a class to handle each event in java?

Tags: java, actionlistener

```
class SomeClass implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
           // do something
        }
}
```

If I have 4 buttons, do I really need to create 4 classes to handle each? 
Is there no way to use a method in the current class instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an *anonymous inner class*. For example:

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        doButton1Stuff();
    }
});
button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        doButton2Stuff();
    }
});
```

An anonymous inner class has access to all the containing class's methods and variables, including `private` ones.

Alternatively, you can create one `ActionListener` and register it for all four buttons. The downside to this is that you then need logic inside the `ActionListener` to figure out which button was pressed (assuming each button does something different):

```
ActionListener a = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == button1) {
            doButton1Stuff();
        }
        if (e.getSource() == button2) {
            doButton2Stuff();
        }
        ...
    }
}
button1.addActionListener(a);
button2.addActionListener(a);
```

Note that this example still uses an anonymous inner class, but you can also use a named class if you prefer.

Finally, with Swing you can take advantage of the `Action` class. `Action`s behave very much like `ActionListener`s but have several features that make GUI development easier in many cases.

Answer (score 2):

No, of course you don't need to create 4 classes. You could simply create one class to handle the button code, 2 classes, or 3, or 4 classes if desired, or even use the current GUI class (`this`) which is not recommended though.

Any of your *inner* listener classes can call methods in the GUI class.

Edit: a view-control example where one control class is used to handle more than one button:

```
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class QuickMVC {
   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      QuickMvcView view = new QuickMvcView();
      QuickMvcControl control = new QuickMvcControl();
      view.setControl(control);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("QuickMVC");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(view.getMainPanel());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class QuickMvcView {
   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
   private QuickMvcControl control;

   public QuickMvcView() {
      JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
      JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");

      button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (control != null) {
               control.button1Action(e);
            }
         }
      });
      button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (control != null) {
               control.button2Action(e);
            }
         }
      });

      mainPanel.add(button1);
      mainPanel.add(button2);
      mainPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Exit") {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (control != null) {
               control.exitAction(e);
            }
         }
      }));
   }

   public JPanel getMainPanel() {
      return mainPanel;
   }

   public void setControl(QuickMvcControl control) {
      this.control = control;
   }
}

class QuickMvcControl {

   public void button1Action(ActionEvent e) {
      System.out.println("called from button 1");
   }

   public void exitAction(ActionEvent e) {
      JComponent comp = (JComponent) e.getSource();
      Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(comp);
      win.dispose();
   }

   public void button2Action(ActionEvent e) {
      System.out.println("called from button 2");
   }

}
```

Comment: How can i handle different buttons in a separate class?

Comment: @lyrae: please explain. What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: If i create one separate class to handle all the buttons class, how can i map a specific button to  a specific method in that class?

Comment: I think you're looking at creating a Model-View-Control type of design pattern. I've done this where each JButton in the View (the GUI) is given an anonymous inner class that calls a method of the control. Hang on, I'll show you.

Comment: @lyrae: please review example code. Feel free to paste any questions or confusions here in comments.

Comment: No no, i was busy. And thank you for the code. I am new to Java and that, along with the other answers, thought me new things. Although I do MVC in python and php, i have never done it in Java and this code is a great read =). thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Attach same listener class, but have different implementation methods based on source of event (which button clicked).

You could consider using getSource() to findout on which object event happend and call corresponding method.